# Running docker builds in parallel in an EC2 instance results in longer build times - why?

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ec2

We are building multiple docker images in the cloud. This is done using this code -

```
func BuildM1Image(tags []string, dockerfile string, contextPath string, dockerRepoUrl string) error {
    dockerExecutable, _ := exec.LookPath("docker")
    awsExecutable, _ := exec.LookPath("aws")
    toTag := tags[0]
    Log("building image with tag " + toTag)
    // to push --> I need the AWS credentials to live in the cloud, pull them

    os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", Secrets[ECR_ACCESS_KEY_NAME])
    os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", Secrets[ECR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_NAME])
    ecrGetCredentialsCMD := &exec.Cmd{
        Path: awsExecutable,
        Args: []string{awsExecutable, "ecr", "get-login-password", "--region", GetRegion()},
        // Stderr: os.Stderr,
        // Stdout: os.Stdout,
    }

    out, _ := ecrGetCredentialsCMD.CombinedOutput()
    // if err != nil {
    //  errorChannel <- err
    //  return
    // }

    dockerEcrLoginCMD := &exec.Cmd{
        Path: dockerExecutable,
        Args: []string{dockerExecutable, "login", "--username", "AWS", "-p", string(out), dockerRepoUrl},
    }

    if err := dockerEcrLoginCMD.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Docker login failed")
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        return err
    }

    buildDockerImage := &exec.Cmd{
        Path: dockerExecutable,
        Args: []string{dockerExecutable, "buildx", "build", "--platform", "linux/amd64", "-t", toTag, "-f", dockerfile, contextPath},
    }

    if err := buildDockerImage.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("docker build failed")
        logError(err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I put the this function inside of a goroutine and kicked off multiple builds. However, the time taken on the builds is slower than if I were to do this sequentially. This only happens in an EC2 instance and not locally (locally we're running this with a M1 mac and it's working as expected).

Why would this happen?

On the EC2 instance we've tried -

1. Increasing the compute/storage
2. Increasing the IOPS

Thanks!